Spring Security custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler is ignored and I can't set into the session
I make a simple Spring Boot application but I have a problem with the session. I would like to set the "customerId" when a customer log in into the application but it doesn't work and my customerId is always null. Here is my code:
// This is my security
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final CustomerService customerService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordencoder;
    private final CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(CustomerService customerService, PasswordEncoder passwordencoder,
                          CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler) {
        this.customerService = customerService;
        this.passwordencoder = passwordencoder;
        this.successHandler = successHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, CustomerRepositor customerRepository) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/api/login")
                        .successHandler(successHandler)
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception
                                .accessDeniedHandler((request, response, customAccessDeniedException) -> {
                                    response.setStatus(403);
                                    response.getWriter().write("Access denied! Sorry, you haven't got permission " +
                                            "to access this page!");
                                })
                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
                );
        return http.build();
    }
   @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder =
                http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(customerService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordencoder);
        return authenticationManager Builder.build();
    } 


Maybe the method don't find the email address in my database?
 @Component
    public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler   {

    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler(CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse    response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        Customer customer = customerRepository.findByEmail(userDetails.getUsername());
        session.setAttribute("customerId", customer.getId());

        response.sendRedirect("/api/login");
    }
}

I use in the PostMan the 'Basic Auth' way for the login.
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class LoginController {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginController.class);


    @GetMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getLoggedInUser(HttpSession session) {
        Object customerId = session.getAttribute("customerId");
        log.info("User has logged in");
        return new ResponseEntity<>("CustomerId: " + customerId, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

The query in my repository:
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.email = :email")
    Customer findByEmail(@Param("email") String email);

I didn't mention, but I build my User in another method. Oh my God, I like the challenges :D
@Service
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public class CustomerService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    private final CustomerMapper customerMapper;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final ProductService productService;

    @Autowired
    public CustomerService(CustomerRepository customerRepository,
                           CustomerMapper customerMapper,
                           PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, ProductService productService) {

        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
        this.customerMapper = customerMapper;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.productService = productService;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Customer user = customerRepository.findByEmail(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with email: " + username);
        }

        String role = user.getUserRole().getRole();
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));


        return User
                .withUsername(user.getEmail())
                .password(user.getPassword())
                .authorities(authorities)
                .build();
    }

Can anybody help me?

I didn't mention, but I build my User by load
